# What to do when there is white ppt formation even after adding dil. sulphuric acid in the mixture of aluminium sulphate and water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I heated the solution containing aluminium sulphate and water with 3 ml dil. sulphuric acid. But I didn't get a clear solution because the solution got milky in color due to the hydrolysis of aluminium sulphate to aluminium hydroxide.

I heated the solution to get a clear solution but couldn't succeed.

I tried to filter the solution but in the filtrate, I got the same milky filtrate.

What to do to get a clear solution?

Comment: What is the context and purpose of this experiment? Hint: Alum is used for cleaning dirty water.

Comment: I have to make the Alum